# Django ImageField: How to select pcitures from modal

Tags: django, modal-dialog, admin, imagefield

I'm, trying to build a website in which one of the function is upload pictures to Modals.So,I use ImageField to finish this. When finishing that,however,I found I need select picture from Modal and ImageField only support select picture from local. I'm searching around for a lone time on new.But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
Here's my code:

modals:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    paragraph = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='course/',editable=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'Course'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Course'

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

admin:

```
admin.site.register(models.Course)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible through ***Django Admin*** interface. You could try [django-filer](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer) (I'm not used this yet.)

Comment: You could do these kind of complex things by using [Django Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/)

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I have to do this by using Forms